# Which python library odoo uses for search, browse and extract data from postgres

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, odoo-12

I am stuck in editing or modifying a report in OpenEducat Odoo App,  i want to know that Which python library odoo uses for search, browse and extract data from postgres, please help.

Comment: Hi,
Please read this blog, where the same thing is explained in detail:-https://mohamedhammad.info/blog/odoo-blog-1/post/professional-odoo-11-deployment-guide-2

Comment: I visited but Sorry this  is not the answer to my question.